# Transform Pandas piled DataFrame to Matrix

Tags: python, pandas

Ultimately I have to perform matrix operations to my dataset.

What I am trying to figure out is how to get piled data (specially from SQL) and transform it to a matrix ? (It can be a 2d numpy array).

Suppose my SQL query returns something of the sort:

```
Name Data         Value 
a    2016-05-01   5
b    2016-05-01   7
c    2016-05-01   7
a    2016-06-01   4
b    2016-06-01   3
c    2016-06-01   2
d    2016-06-01   2
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
Data/Name    a   b   c   d
2016-05-01   5   7   7   NaN
2016-06-01   4   3   2   2
```

I know I could loop through all values, but what I'm looking for here is performance. Is there a more direct/fast/pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) against your DataFrame.

For a given `df`:

```
df
Out[19]: 
  Name        Data  Value
0    a  2016-05-01      5
1    b  2016-05-01      7
2    c  2016-05-01      7
3    a  2016-06-01      4
4    b  2016-06-01      3
5    c  2016-06-01      2
6    d  2016-06-01      2
```

Call `pivot` by setting the index and colums you want to use from your original DataFrame:

```
df.pivot('Data', 'Name')
Out[20]: 
           Value               
Name           a    b    c    d
Data                           
2016-05-01   5.0  7.0  7.0  NaN
2016-06-01   4.0  3.0  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! Can I choose a value for missing values ?

Comment: `df.pivot('Data', 'Name').fillna(42.0)`